# How to remove black topbar on activity animation

Tags: android, animation

I defined scale animation from 0 to 1 for entering activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.scale, 0);
```

In application tag in Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

But I get a black topbar on the entering activity, while it scales... looks very ugly since the activity doesn't show this topbar. How do I hide it?

Edit: The anim xml is this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<scale 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
/>
</set>
```

(set element is actually not necessary, have it because I was testing with other animations before).

The black topbar hides behind the system's topbar while the activity becomes it's final size.

P.S. I'll try out another idea tomorrow... hide the status bar in onCreate of the launched activity... since this black space is exactly the space occupied by the status bar. If you have any other suggestion, please post it!

Comment: Could you post your `anim` code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the action bar, from Android 4.0. If so, for Android 4.0+, specify:

```
android:theme="@android:style/heme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

You can specify this separately for 4.0+, as for 2.x which does not have the Holo theme.

Comment: I'm not refering to the action bar. Using a 2.3.3 device and developing for 2.1.

Comment: The app doesn't show the titlebar, it just appears while scaling the activity from 0 to "0.9"

Comment: What black bar are you talking about then?

Comment: Well, a black topbar which appears while scaling the activity, I don't know what it is.

Comment: It has the same dimensions as the device's system bar, so I think it's like the space behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this question, paste next code before code setContextView(...)

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT );
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( colorDrawable );
```

It works fine for me!